# Is there a name for a person who loves waterfalls?

Tags: single-word-requests

I love waterfalls and have noticed that there seems to be a name for everyone who loves something. I've found names for people who love water, running water as in a creek or river, the ocean, salt water, but no waterfalls. Is there such a word yet? There are entire books about waterfalls and even waterfall tours and trips. Lots of waterfall lovers out there.
Thanks ~

Comment: ["Waterfall lover"](https://www.google.ae/search?q=%22Waterfall+lover%22)

Comment: I love waterfalls too, particularly the smaller ones.  You say there are words for running water lovers and ocean water lovers.  It would strengthen your question if you gave those names in your question.

Comment: You can coin the word _cataractophile_ [from Latin _cataracta_ or Greek _καταρράκτης_  (katarráktis) waterfall + Latin _-phila_,  Ancient Greek _φίλος_ loving, dear]. I could find [a reference](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22cataractophiles%22&*) in Google Books also.

Comment: @ermanen: I'm guessing [*cataractophile*](http://zambianwaterfalls.blogspot.co.uk/) (who blogs about Zambian Waterfalls), chose his handle for that very reason. I was already searching for it as you posted your comment, so it obviously worked for *me.*

Answer (score 2):

[Rheophilic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rheophilic), meaning "preferring or living in flowing water", seems the closest match, but that is much broader in its meaning and seems more applicable to "running water as in a creek or river" that you noted in your post. Then there's the even broader meaning for hydrophilous which can mean "loving or preferring water."

It does seem there might be a word for people who share your love for waterfalls, since there are many, since there are words for what would seem to be much more obscure loves. E.g., [coulrophiles](http://mentalfloss.com/article/53610/15-philes-and-what-they-love) "don't just find clowns, jesters, and mimes amusing. They're sexually attracted to them." And there's a word, [thalassophilous](http://phrontistery.info/love.html), for those who are fond of the sea.

Edit: from  ermanen's suggestion, I found the following quote in [Guide to Little-known Waterfalls of Zambia](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=cataractophile), a book published in 2004, which [Amazon shows as being out of stock currently](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9982995200):

> It has become quite a popular trip since then, and, with the advent of
>   Kamikazi Camping - an outfit that guides self-drive cataractophiles
>   [waterfalls enthusiasts] - has even gone commercial

At least one of the authors, who are Quentin Allen, Ilse Mwanza, and Heather Chalcraft, appears to be associated with the blog referenced in FumbleFingers comment.